# What's the best practices for frontend in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i'm a front-end dev currently working in a team on a big Ruby on Rails project. It is not SPA. All the page rendering is done on server side.

Project had dozens of views with logic like

```
if true render this partial else render another partial
```

I try to follow DRY principles, i learned a lot from [arkency blog](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/07/6-front-end-techniques-for-rails-developers-part-i-from-big-ball-of-mud-to-separated-concerns/), and tried to implement as much reusable components as possible.

But I feel the lack the of things like `componentDidMount` from React.

So my question is: is it ok to write inline javascript (i.e. add logic) in rails partials? 
And what's the best way to write Javascript for maintainable Rails apps?

Comment: you are going to get a lot of opinion based answers (so your question may get closed), however, I still think it's a good question. This is a really important issue in Rails right now, because until recently I have never seen a Rails app that did a good job at organizing JavaScript. I'll post an answer shortly, but keep it mind - my answer will be completed opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it ok to write inline javascript (i.e. add logic) in rails partials?

- My answer is no. It's not maintainable and it's ugly.

> And what's the best way to write Javascript for maintainable Rails apps?

- See below

You are going to get a lot of opinion based answers. There really is not *true answer* to this problem. My answer is 1) opinion-based and 2) no where near perfect.

That being said, I'd like to offer my own opinion. I have seen and built large and small sized Rails applications over the past few years (apps of 10 js files and apps of 100+), and I have been very dissatisfied with the organization of JavaScript in those apps and the apps I've seen across GitHub. I've seen countless JavaScript files full of unorganized and disassociated code. That doesn't seem very Rails-like to me. Over the past few months, I've been trying to find the solution to this, and there is one solution I found that gets the closest to a well organized JavaScript codebase on a Rails app. And I think it stays true to some Rails ideals. One downside to this method is it litters the global scope...I'd love to here from a JS developer on how to fix this.

Here is the Medium post:

https://medium.com/@cblavier/rails-with-no-js-framework-26d2d1646cd#.36zis335e

I have made a few tweaks to this, because sometimes you need to share code, for example, code that powers a shared form for your users. However, I'd like to give all credit to @cblavier. So please please take the time to read his post, because it has a *ton* of great information, and I won't go into complete detail below.

**Requirements**: Coffeescript, Turbolinks, and jQuery

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

def js_class_name
  action = case action_name
    when 'create' then 'New'
    when 'update' then 'Edit'
    else action_name
  end.camelize

  "Views.#{controller_name.camelize}.#{action}View"
end
```

For the above helper, you will need to account for namespaced controllers if you app has namespaced controllers. That should be fairly easy though. I think the below would do the trick.

```
"Views.#{controller_path.camelize.gsub('::', '.')}.#{action}View"
```

Alright, now you want to add that to the `<body>` tag in your layout.

```
<body data-class-name="<%= js_class_name %>">
```

Time for the javascript!

```
# initializer.coffee
pageLoad = ->
  className = $('body').attr('data-class-name')
  initializePage(className)
  initializePageBase(className)

initializePage = (className) ->
  window.applicationView = try
    eval("new #{className}()")
  catch error
    new Views.ApplicationView()

  window.applicationView.render()

initializePageBase = (className) ->
  modules = className.split('.')
  modules.splice(modules.length - 1, 1)

  window.baseView = try
    eval("new #{modules.join('.')}.BaseView")

  window.baseView.render() unless window.baseView is undefined

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', pageLoad # turbolinks:load is master branch of turbolinks, if you are using older version, it's page:load
$(document).on 'page:before-change', ->
  window.applicationView.cleanup()
  true
$(document).on 'page:restore', ->
  window.applicationView.cleanup()
  pageLoad()
  true
```

---

```
# app/assets/javascripts/views/application_view.coffee
window.Views ||= {}

class Views.ApplicationView
  render: ->
    # pretty much global JS code can be initialized here. It's nice
    # to keep the render() method clean though. Like this:
    @setupElements()

  setupElements: ->
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip() # just an example

  cleanup: ->
```

---

Now that you have those setup, it's time to start adding your page JavaScript. Here is just a example of one for the page. `users_controller#show`

```
Views.Users ||= {}

class Views.Users.ShowView extends Views.ApplicationView
  constructor: ->
    # find and cache DOM objects, etc
    # ex:
    @someButton = $('[data-behavior=expand-user-info]')

  render: ->
    super() # this is important. It calls render() on ApplicationView

    # example stuff
    @bindEventListeners()

   bindEventListeners: ->
     t = this

     @someButton.on 'click', ->
       t.expandUserInfo()

  expandUserInfo: ->
    alert('woohoo!')

  cleanup: ->
    super()
```

If you noticed earlier, in the `initializer.coffee` method, we called a method, `initializePageBase()`. When I was using the structure [from that Medium post](https://medium.com/@cblavier/rails-with-no-js-framework-26d2d1646cd#.35dbq1c26), I ran into an issue where I needed the same javascript on both the `edit` and `new` views. That `initializePageBase()` is the first step to solving it. It will look for a BaseView class. Here is an example:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/views/users/base_view.coffee
Views.Users ||= {}

class Views.Users.BaseView # you don't need to extend ApplicationView here, because we are already initializing it.
  render: ->
    # code
```

Comment: Thx for great answer! I'll need some time to dig your ideas, but i already liked the idea of delivering js scope with app helper .

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is to use the react.rb gem (and the reactive_rails_generator to do the installation)

This will allow you to write your views in react style you are used to.

Even though its not a single page app react.rb can simply as your templating langugage.   If you have some interactive on page features you are good to go.

There is also a reactive-record gem which might be worth looking into.